# Step into a web service application from a web forms application

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to debug a web service that I created using VS2012 in C#.
I created a test application in the form of a web forms application that calls the methods in the web service.  They are both on my local computer.

I need to be able to step into the web service application to debug and I looked at all the information from others trying to do the same thing.  But I can't seem to get it to step into the service method.

These applications are in separate solution workspaces.  I have tried setting both applications as starting apps but only one appears in the multiple solutions window.  I have tried attaching the web service process to the web application but this does not work either.

Can anyone describe how I can step into a web service that is called from a web forms application?

Comment: Did you attached w3wp.exe?

Comment: I don't see that process in the 'Available Processes' when I try to attach a process.

Comment: check :
1.Show processes from all users 2.Show processes in all sesions

Comment: I have the 'Show processes from all users' checked.  I don't see where I can indicate 'show processes in all sessions'.  There is still no w3wp.exe in the process window.

Comment: try reach a page on localhost w3wp will not show up unless an instance of the web application is running.

Comment: OK...Now I get it!  Thanks Daniel for your patience.  With the web application running, I went to the web service project and 'Attached the Process' and w3wp was available.  Now, i am on my way!  THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone trying to figure out how to debug a web service.  You need to do the following:

1. Start your web application that calls the web service.  Put in a breakpoint somewhere before the web service method is called.
2. When you hit the breakpoint, go to the web service project and to go to 
   Debug -> Attach to Process
3. In this Attach to Process Dialog, scroll thru the Available Processes and find:
   w3wp.exe
4. Click Attach button to attach the web service to the web app process.

When you step thru your web app, you should be able to step into the web service method.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your web service is deployed and running, and that you are having hard times breaking in webservice code:

First, make sure web service is deployed in debug configuration (project properties) - that means that debug symbols are generated at compile time.

Second, ensure that it is actually "listening", i.e. no IP/port conflicts or other issues.

Third, make sure you have Just in Time Debugging (see my comment) enabled.

Add this line in your webservice code, where you want web service to stop:

`System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();`

Or you can attach it via code and then just use break points:

`System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();`

Now, forget about the other assumptions. An alternative approach - and your question doesn't show why this is not working - is to simply run/host your web service by hitting Debug inside its Visual Studio solution, with the web service (it's .asmx file) being the Start Up Project. If that works, you practically have VS debugger attach to a running process and could just set your breakpoints.

In both scenarios you need to understand the IP address and port combination where your service is listening and use that address in your tester.

Comment: How do you attach the web service to the web application?

Comment: Suppose your web service is hosted under local IIS. When above statements are baked into your code, when webservice is "hit" from your windows forms app, you should get the ["Just in Time Debugging"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx)  prompt, which will help you attach to the process that runs your web service.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply Attach that service to the Process using `CTRL + ALT + P` then find that port on which your service is running. and then the second thing you have to consume that service in your webform using `WebRequest` to complete the debug process.

**Here is the Example**
[image]

**Code for Consuming the WCF into your Project**

```
#region Calling LOGIN Serv

        string URL = "http://localhost:32319/ServiceEmployeeLogin.svc/login";
        WebRequest wrGETURL;
        wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(URL + "/" + emp_username + "/" + emp_password + "/" + emp_type);
        wrGETURL.Method = "POST";
        wrGETURL.ContentType = @"application/json; charset=utf-8";
        HttpWebResponse webresponse = wrGETURL.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
#endregion
```

Comment: Note that this is how you might consume a WCF REST service - a SOAP service would be different.

Comment: yeah @JohnSaunders the process of consuming the SOAP serv. is completely different and it's comparatively easier than REST.

Comment: I am using a SOAP service.  Sorry, forgot to mention

Comment: then you can simply follow this [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9KusEDQpqyE) hope this will sort out your problem.

Comment: that video just tells you have to add a web service to a web app.  I need to know how to step into a web service from the web app.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your solutions via Visual studio, if so, you need to set breakpoints in each of these solutions and start the application from VS.Net. VS will automatically take care of attaching the process and breaking into your code

Comment: I have breakpoints in both solutions.  When I start the web forms application, and try to step into the web service method, it steps over it.  I do not get any error but the web service method should insert a record into the database and it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Open 2 Visual Studio instances, in one load the solution that is a web service in second load the solution that is consuming this web service.Set break points and run first VS/solution in debug mode, local asp.net development server should start as example `http://localhost:5152/`

In second VS/Solution use the URL from first (local asp.net development server) include necessary path, for example `http://localhost:5152/yourwebservicepath/webservicename`

likely put it in web.config before debug

Run second VS/solution, once this project will call the webservice first VS should start blinking in taskbar indicating that break point was hit, switch to first VS and step thru from there.

Please note that if you will debug for too long, second VS/application will encounter timeout from the server as it is hold by the break point(s)

**UPDATE:**
Other way:

If both web service project and consuming app is in the same solution:
Set web service project as startup project and start debugging
In solution explorer right click on the consuming application, select Debug -> Start new instance. Now you can debug both applications at once from one VS/same solution